# Elements in container not inline

Tags: css

Why isn't the first element inline with the other elements in the container? I can't figure out why it's doing that. The snippet works, but it doesn't when I run it on the webpage. What could cause an element doing this?

[image]

```css
.search {
    background-color: #2a7a2e;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    }
.searchtag {
    margin: 4px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    }
cloudcontainer {
  width: 940px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  float: left;
}

cloudcontainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.tagcloud {
  background-color: #2a7a2e;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<form id="search">
<input class="searchtag" type="text" id="search" name="search">
<button class="search" type="submit" formaction="go.php" 
method="GET">Search</button>
</form>

<cloudcontainer>
  <form id="search"><button class="tagcloud" type="submit" formaction="go.php" method="GET">zzz</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="search" name="search" value="zzz"></form>
  <form id="search"><button class="tagcloud" type="submit" formaction="go.php" method="GET">aa</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="search" name="search" value="aa"></form>
  <form id="search"><button class="tagcloud" type="submit" formaction="go.php" method="GET">aaa</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="search" name="search" value="aaa"></form>
</cloudcontainer>
```

Comment: the code snippet you added seem to be inline

Comment: The code snippet you posted works fine. Unless we can reproduce the problem, it will be difficult to diagnose. Please take the time to include all relevant code

Comment: I know I should paste all code. I've added all relevant code and I dont understand why the result is different.

Answer (score 0):

Adding below resolved the issue.

```
<form style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
```